# Can I use .net core on visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, .net-core

Is, or will .net core be available to use on visual studio 2013? Or it will be available only on visual studio 2015?

Thanks

Comment: Hmya, that question doesn't make a lot of sense.  Write a Silverlight, Phone, Store or Universal app, they use .NETCore.

Comment: So guessing from this, I can write and run an asp.net 5 web site in Linux by creating a silverlight project using VS2010? this seems very odd by me.

Comment: Get VS2013 running on Linux first, come back when you're done.

Comment: that is because i am refering to this. [dotnetfoundation.org](http://www.dotnetfoundation.org/netcore5)

Comment: That was clear.  Open-sourcing .NETCore means squat to programmers that have access to VS2013, they have been able to use it for a long time.  It was open-sourced so programmers that **don't** use Microsoft tools and runtime environments can take advantage of it.  Eventually.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to build against the .NET Core 5 contracts in Visual Studio 2013 by creating a Portable Class Library that targets .NET Framework 4.5 and Windows 8. You'll need to manually edit the .csproj file and add the following.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <ImplicitlyExpandTargetFramework>false</ImplicitlyExpandTargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then install the [System.Runtime](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime) NuGet package and other .NET Core 5 packages.

The resulting assembly will be able to execute on any .NET Core 5-based framework including .NET Framework 4.6, ASP.NET 5 & .NET Native.

Note, this is the same technique used to build the .NET Core assemblies in the [corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) repository.

Comment: Are you sure this is possible? I have tried to build a .netcore console app in VS 2013, and I cannot install the .netcore package, because it requires NuGet package manager version 3.0 or above. Version 3 of the package manager doesn't yet support VS 2013.

Comment: Things have changed A LOT since this post... Check out [Getting started with .NET Core](http://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/)

Comment: Yeah, confusing: [For ASP.NET Core 1.0 + .NET Core RC instructions, please go to the Get ASP.NET Core 1.0 website.](http://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/)

Answer (score 2):

An empty ASP.NET Core application can be built in VS2013 by doing the following steps:

1. Create a **Console App** project that targets at least .NET Framework 4.5.2 (using 4.5.1 is possible but [support has now ended](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/)).
2. Install the following NuGet Packages:

   - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
   - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
3. Add existing item to project: [solution root]\packages\Libuv.[version]\runtimes\[os]\native\libuv.dll.
4. For the above file, set the property "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always"
5. Produce the necessary Startup.cs and Program.cs files

**Basic Code (from the [Getting Started Tutorial](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started.html)):**

**Program.cs**

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(context =>
        {
            return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from ASP.NET Core!");
        });
    }
}
```