# Targeting .NET Core on visual studio 2013

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-core

I developed an open source library on nuget. ([NBitcoin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NBitcoin/))

I want to target netcore and compile it on VS2013, and I have read [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29084960/can-i-use-net-core-on-visual-studio-2013) which say I must target net45+win8 to do that.

But, now nuget support the target to netcore as well as dnx ([Link](http://blog.nuget.org/20150331/nuget-2.8.5.html)).

My goal is that someone following [this tutorial on .NET dev on linux or mac](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html#setting-up-your-development-environment) can resolve my project on nuget and that It Just Works.
Currently nuget is resoling the package which target net45, and some code crash at runtime because class I am using are not present in netcore. So, at the end of the day, what should I target ?

Comment: It is a pretty black-and-white problem, if you need a class that's not available in .NETCore then you cannot target it.  So don't try.  Do keep in mind that you're actually talking about CoreCLR, it is a work in progress.  Don't keep the class name a secret.

Comment: I'm not against removing features if I need to compile. But I don't know which target to choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target netcore45, or upgrade to VS2015 and target netcore50 I think. VS2015 Community edition is free for open source projects, so once it is available on July 20 you can install it.

It is very likely that .NET Core and DNX support won't come to VS2013.

Comment: What is the difference between dnxnetcore and netcore50 ? which one should I choose ?

Comment: It would be lengthy to reveal the details, so you might get started from this [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2015/06/18/demystifying-pcls-net-core-dnx-and-uwp-redux.aspx)