# Possible to @inject into razor views in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

Was wondering if there was a way to to DI into views and found this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection

However I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with Framework 4.5.1 and the @inject keyword is not available. Would I have to get new version of Visual Studio or is it possible to get access to this keyword by updating Framework or something else?

Comment: You need to upgrade to use [asp.net-core-mvc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry to be picky, but are you saying I need to upgrade Visual Studio or the Framework or the version of MVC I'm using? And you say "to use asp.net-core-mvc" but I the question is specifically regarding the use of the inject keyword. I only mention this because you might not be aware that I am actually otherwise able to use the new Dependency Injection stuff created for core in 4.5.1 by downloading the appropriate assemblies. Likewise, I'm wondering if, say, I could update to a higher level of MVC with current version of Visual Studio to gain access to the keyword.

Comment: @StephenMuecke And I get that the ultimate answer is probably that I need to upgrade version of Visual Studio, but just want to be sure :)

Comment: Its possible with VS-2013 (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29084960/can-i-use-net-core-on-visual-studio-2013))

Comment: @StephenMuecke lol, that might answer my questions in the details somehow, but really I am not trying to use .net core in vs 2013. I think you're making the assumption that the inject keyword is inseparable from ".net core" and maybe you're right but you're not phrasing as such. I am able to use other components from .net core without "using .net core".

Comment: But obviously it's a moot point... if you knew a way you would have told me. Thanks for your response!

Comment: `@inject` was introduced in `.net-core` - it does not exist in `4.5.1 ` (and what do you mean you can use components from `.net core` without using `.net core`?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can otherwise use the dependency injection stuff as outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection. It's available in Nuget Packages and works in 4.5 (well, the 1.1.1 version does, but the the 2.0 version I think you have to have 4.6).